# Unable to set the User-Agent as transport Header in WSO2 EI 6.1

Tags: wso2, esb, wso2-enterprise-integrator, integrator, wso2-esb

I am trying to invoke an external REST service from WSO2 EI 6.1.
This REST service needs the transport header User-Agent to be set. 
I used the below code to set the transport value but looks like WSO2 does not recognize it.

```
<header name="User-Agent" scope="transport" value="3PPUser/5.0/1.0"/>
```

I even tried changing the **http.user.agent.preserve** to true at passthru-http.properties, but no successs.

Not sure if I am missing something. Please help!

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: This is probably not the answer, but please note that `3PPUser/5.0/1.0` is not a correct value for [`User-Agent`](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-5.5.3). `3PPUser/5.0` would be.

Comment: @VasiliyFaronov - Thanks for your reply, but I have tried the value `3PPUser/5.0/1.0` for User-Agent from the POSTMAN tool and it worked fine. Whereas using `3PPUser/5.0` was not successful.